# Hello i m stuck with Laravel eloquent relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i have two tables deals and products, on product table i just have product description whic can be assigned to one than more deals , now i want to display product description on deal page,but my relation is not working correctly,
[product table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmRzT.png)

[deal table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMJjK.png)

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    //
protected $guarded=[];

 

    public function deals()
    {
    return $this->belongsTo(Deal::class,'product_slug','product_id');

    }

}
  





<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Deal extends Model
{
    //
protected $guarded=[];

 


    public function products()
    {
   return $this->hasMany(Product::class,'product_slug','product_id');

    }


}
```

this is how i m calling the function in controller

```
    public function index()
        {
    $title='Today Deal';
    $deals=Deal::with('products')->get();

// dd($deals);
// return;
return view('welcome',compact('title','deals'));

   }
```

i can see the product data when i do dd but on view i m getting this error when i access the product data
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$title (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\bargin\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)
this how i acces the the product data inside the deal loop

```
                                   <p>{{$deal->products()->title}}</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is inside your loop. `<p>{{$deal->products()->title}}</p>`.

When you access a relationship using the function call, `products()`, you are actually returning an instance of the relationship to where you can add query methods to.

For example, you can use `$deal->products()->where(...)->get()`.

---

In order to access the actual products, you just use `$deal->products`.

```php
@foreach($deal->products as $product)
    {{ $product->title }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: but deal title and description is single which can be used with each product i have already done the same relation in laravle 6 but in 8 these issue occurs

Comment: @attaullah Not sure what you're saying here. Looking back at the answer I did pluralized deal to deals. I'll fix it.

Comment: @attaullah this relationship will let you access the products related to the deal you're on. In order to get the title and the description of the deal, you can just reference `$deal->description`, `deal->title`, and I also see you're passing in a `$title` from the controller.